# “É” become “Ã©” C# Encoding from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1

Tags: c#, .net, encoding, utf-8, html-agility-pack

I am facing a problem in converting `UTF-8` to `ISO-8859-1` while using `htmlagilitypack`

```
string url = "http://www.example.com";
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
HtmlDocument htmldocument = new HtmlDocument();
htmldocument.Load(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8);

HtmlNode headnode = htmldocument.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//head");
HtmlNode titlenode = headnode.SelectSingleNode(".//title");
string title = titlenode.InnerText;
```

**title output is `Nice CafÃ©`**

**This is how I tried to Encode**

```
Encoding iso = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
Encoding utf8 = Encoding.UTF8;
byte[] utfBytes = utf8.GetBytes(title);
byte[] isoBytes = Encoding.Convert(utf8, iso, utfBytes);
string Fixedtitle = iso.GetString(isoBytes);
```

**Fixedtitle output should be `Nice Café`**

I think problem is when iso-8859-1 was incorrectly forced into UTF-8. But I unable to fix the output text.

Please help me. Best regards.

Comment: Your example code is ignoring the response headers, which may include the encoding. Use `htmldocument.Load(response.GetResponseStream(), response.ContentEncoding)`

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski: Thanks for notifying me. my example url have `<meta charset="UTF-8">` present, so should I set UTF-8 `ContentEncoding` ?

Comment: Hmm if there's an encoding meta tag in the document, HAP should have picked it up. But then [MDN says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta) *"The HTTP Content-Type header and any BOM elements have precedence over this element."*, so you can still try to use the response's encoding. I've never used HAP so I don't know how well it adheres to the standard.

Comment: I tried but no luck, I think `ISO-8859-1` characters are present on the web page and when getting response as `UTF-8` it failed to convert those characters to `UTF-8`. Is there a way if we can convert the output string later to `ISO-8859-1` like I tried in my code?

Comment: I wouldn't attempt manual conversions since they may fail at a later time. Perhaps there's a bug in HAP, you could try AngleSharp instead and see if it has the same issue.

Comment: This went wrong on the web site server itself.  It read utf-8 encoded text but interpreted with, say, Encoding.Default.  Trying to recover from that is not generally possible.  A half-baked attempt to recover is to use Encoding.Default.GetBytes() followed by Encoding.UTF8.GetString().  Gets you the coffee you want in this specific case, it can't work for everything.  Contact the web site owner to get him to fix his bug.

Comment: @HansPassant: Thanks for your comment, so the page who have even a single `ISO-8859-1` character should have `<meta charset="ISO-8859-1"`or we can set both? I have fixed the encoding problem btw.

Comment: The web site encodes its output correctly into utf8.  This went wrong one level down, it read the data wrong.  Maybe even deeper and a record in the dbase it uses got mangled by whatever code entered the data into the dbase.  Encoding problems can strike anywhere.  Talk to the site owner to get this resolved, we can only guess at it here.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you've already solved this problem, but follow the code that worked for me (I had a similar problem)

```
byte[] data = Encoding.Default.GetBytes("Nice CafÃ©");
string output = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
```

Result in DotnetFiddle:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I think we all saw the problem in reverse, we want to convert into UTF-8, not the oposite

Code should be like this:

```
Encoding iso = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
byte[] data = iso.GetBytes("Nice CafÃ©");
string output = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
```